# Return values not in another vector

Tags: r

below is the sample I need to return. So to return all values not in `asd2`, i have used `%in%`. But it is returning True or False. Is it possible to have values retured?

```
> asd2 <- c("A")
> asd <- c("A","B","C")
> newasd <- asd %in% asd2
> newasd
[1]  TRUE FALSE FALSE
```

Expected outcome

```
newasd 
[1]  "B" "C"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get all values that match, use:

```
asd[asd %in% asd2]
```

...returns:

```
[1] "A"
```

To get values that aren't in asd2, use this:

```
asd[!asd %in% asd2]
```

...returns:

```
[1] "B" "C"
```

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
setdiff(asd,asd2)
[1] "B" "C"
```

Answer (score 2):

You can remove elements in an object using the logical values you've created like this

```
asd[-newasd]
[1] "B" "C"
```